# How add option `writeConcern` in mongo-go-driver?

Tags: database, mongodb, go

I do not understand how to add recording parameters for MongoDB using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)

Example request

```
c.client.Database(MONGO_DATABASE).Collection(*packet.ID).InsertMany(nil, packet.Item, opt)
```

How to specify the necessary parameters in `opt`?

Comment: What is "mongo-go-native" ?

Comment: @AlexBlex this driver for MongoDB (for golang)

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/4cb519e8e22f6c951c9f1c521296966efb224e49/mongo/collection.go#L326 suggests it gets the WC from the collection. Give it a try. It seems the driver is quite young, so the source code is your best friend in terms of documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**VERSION 1.0**

In MongoDB Go driver production release you can set `writeConcern` as below:

```
import (    
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"     
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"  
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"     
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/writeconcern" 
)

mongoURI := "mongodb://server:port/"
opts := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI).SetWriteConcern(writeconcern.New(writeconcern.WMajority()))

client, err := mongo.NewClient(opts)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
defer cancel()
err = client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

collection := client.Database("database").Collection("collection")
```

See also:

- [mongo-driver/mongo/options](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options)
- [mongo-driver/mongo/writeconcern](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/writeconcern)

**VERSION 0.0.16**

Using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/), you can set a [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) option as below example:

```
import(
  "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson"
  "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/core/writeconcern"
  "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo"
  "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/collectionopt"
)

// Example document 
document := bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
                 bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
                   "foo",
                   bson.EC.Int32("bar", 101),
                 ),
               )

// Set majority write concern
wMajority := writeconcern.New(writeconcern.WMajority())

database := client.Database("database")
collection := database.Collection("collection", collectionopt.WriteConcern(wMajority))

_, err = collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), document)
```

Can also use `W(int)` to specify an arbitrary number of `mongod` instances. See more [writeconcern/writeconcern.go](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v0.0.16/core/writeconcern/writeconcern.go)